# using tinybutstrong i can generate docx but it corrupted

Tags: docx, opentbs, tinybutstrong

1. i am using **laravel** and **php** and **tiny-but-strong-world
   engine**
2. i have php file that will generate the docx and  i have sample template
   docx

but i got the output like this

PK!ߤ?Z [Content_Types].xml ¢( ´??E?·Ub袪*>-R?{V?¼þ¾QU l"%3?3Vƃ?l µw%?=^i7+??d&???l4¼½L60#µÒ? O£X?*V$z3?3?½??p)Oµ^  ²?}nH"d??gL`´??|Prۃs??PW?t4Q+?"¦wa©¯|T\y¹°¤,N??U¥%´?-D/?¢­X¡ݞÿ(¦¼?U>\þ??(a?§P£¨F?«K!ʑ¦U?¤z§1gw1?6§1?'0ª¿Ŵª`w?¸?4´5(K@S z¿?gX§¹@? ?ǇP?P¶&­:2UH?¤#?Ð?$gq?C:§??I ?M¾??W?D¤³4K?`"»!iq;??r#9?r?H:6VW¼µ?½¾4}?·N?£µɡ??.XQ-Ӳ??4?v wO9qgj??5TnO1¿??˟F?½?&??Cn&D?¹???v??h ¹S?`¬¦z?[}].-s¶*7h?Ю7{]?²?«??IJH y<º^YA

Comment: the sample template and data from MySQL not merging in docx

Comment: What makes you know the file is corrupted ? The ouput you give seems ok since a DOCX is a ZIP archive.

Comment: I've solved it  by this "buffer"    **  ob_end_clean();
ob_end_flush();**

Comment: ok nice, it could be useful if you post your own reply

Comment: yeah ...  the problem is html